Flutter Push Notification Icon Showing White in color
Flutter push notification  using flutter_local_notification show white box for some devices how to fix this
Most of the device showing the notification icon correctly but some device have the problem

res/drawable/aaaa_logo.png is the only icon i added

AndroidManifest.xml



Try to generate your notification icon from AndroidAssetStudio, it gives transparent background.

@DroidFlutter after that paste the files to 'res' folder , any further steps required ?

If it is from the icon side then no further steps are required.

i added drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-xxxhdpi
but still same issue

Have you tried to add your xxxx_logo in mipmap folders and then inside manifest file:   "" and make sure that this  should be at  level NOT in the  level.

Generate icon using icon.kitchen and put in your res folder, in your manifest file use

It is worked for me.
showFlutterNotification method icon is not useful in this case.

Try icon.kitchen for generating icon. Use Monochrome or once with transparent bg for your aaaa_logo.png file.

Add icon inside the drawable folder for notification icon.
Note: The notification icon which you want to add should be transparent. If the transparent icon is not added, then by default grey icon is getting displayed even you followed all steps properly.
Try this to generate icon: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html

In my experience in this thing. You shouldn't config the icon manualy.
You should use "icon-set-creator" library.
This lib will help you generate all the icon from one picture in exactly the location/directory for both IOS and Android.
After that, the notification icon will show the same icon with you application icon automatically.

Step 1: add flutter_launcher_icons: any in to your dependency
Step 2: add this config to you pubspec.yaml file:

flutter_icons:
  android: "ic_launcher"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/vitadairy_icon.jpg" // this is your main icon.


Step 3: run flutter pub get and wait for load dependency.
Step 4: run flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main.
Step 5: Enjoin the result ❤️ ❤️ ❤️

Thanks
